# Performance issue when trying to query based on concatenated columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two tables

Table1:

```
-------------------------------
id | pid | name | place | num |
-------------------------------
```

Table2:

```
------------------
pid | name | key |
------------------
```

Now i am writing a query which is a concatenation of two columns, one from table1 and the other from table2.

```
select * 
from table1 join table2 
on table1.pid = table2.pid 
and table2.key + '-' + table1.num = 'ABC-123'
```

Since this concatenation is done on two tables which again has to scan most of the rows for the result, the result fetch is very slow and not instantaneous which would be expected.

In such a case what would be advisable. Can anyone help me with this.

Initially it was thought to create a function based index so that there would be some performance gain, but I am not sure whether this will help or not. Moreover I was not able to get a way to create a function based index on two columns from different tables.

New Addition:

The answers given were legitimate but I felt it is going away from my actual requirement. If I have a requirement like this

```
select table2.key + '-' + table1.num identity
from table1 join table2 
on table1.pid = table2.pid
```

The actual requirement is that I have to concatenate the values from both tables and expose it in a view. Then anyone can query on that column identity from the view. So basically the concatenation will be a must.

Comment: If all columns is not required Always select specific columns from tables like select column1, column2 from tablename.

Comment: looks to me like table2.key + '-' + table1.num = 'ABC-123' should be part of a where clause not part of the join criteria

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       JOIN table2
         ON table1.pid = table2.pid
            AND table2.KEY = 'ABC'
            AND table1.num = '123'
```

Comment: Just want to add that the expression in the original query was non-sargable because of the concatenation.  Specifying the individual predicates provides sargable expressions so indexes on those columns can be used efficiently.  It doesn't matter if an `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` is used.  Some additional index tuning using the `pid`, `KEY` and `num` columns may be needed to get the most optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using one string 'ABC-123' try split it to 'ABC' & '123'-

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 
    ON table1.pid = table2.pid 
    AND 
    table2.key IN ('ABC')  
    AND 
    table1.num IN ('123')
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be able to query on the concatenated value efficiently, you can create an indexed view.  Additional view columns can be added as needed.  Be aware of the `SET` option requirements for updating the tables referenced by the indexed view (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx).  If you are not using SQL Server Enterprise or Developer edition, you'll need to add the `NOEXPAND` hint to queries in order for the view index to be considered by the optimizer.

Also, I strongly suggest you avoid using reserved keywords as column names (`key` and `identity`);

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.IndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT table2.[key] + '-' + table1.num [identity]
FROM dbo.table1 
JOIN dbo.table2 
    ON table1.pid = table2.pid;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_IndexedView ON IndexedView([identity]);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only searching on one value at a time, you can split the values up programmatically. This is similar to the other answers, but does the splitting for you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Get_Concat_ID
    @ConcatID AS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Table1Num as varchar(20) = SUBSTRING(@ConcatID, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @ConcatID))
    declare @Table2Key as varchar(20) = SUBSTRING(@ConcatID, CHARINDEX('-', @ConcatID)+1, LEN(@ConcatID))

    select *
    from table1 join table2 
        on table1.pid = table2.pid
        and table1.num = @Table1Num
        and table2.key = @Table2Key
END
GO
```

Then, you can just call usp_Get_Concat_ID 'ABC-123'.